# Python2.7: How to get correct Chinese character?

Tags: string, python-2.7, unicode

**I am having a problem with opening Chinese string in XML file.**

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from io import open
>>> file = open(u'/senti/cet_2.xml', encoding = u'utf-8')
>>> contents = file.read()
>>> contents
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<document>\n
<Topic>\u5584\u826f \u4e30\u5bcc \u9ad8\u8d35</Topic>\n    <title T="\u5584\u826f\uff0c \u4e30\u5bcc\uff0c\u9ad8\u8d35">\n
```

**However, I have no problem with the same code in Python 3.3**

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]  on win32
>>> file = open('/Senti/cet_2.xml', encoding = 'utf-8')
>>> contents = file.read()
>>> contents
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<document>\n
<Topic>善良 丰富 高贵</Topic>\n    <title T="善良，丰富，高贵">\n
```

**How can I get the correct string in Python 2.7?**

Comment: It's already correct Chinese characters. `print contents` will show you what you want.

Comment: import codecs... file = codecs.open('/Senti/cet_2.xml', 'r', 'utf-8')

Comment: thanks, problem solved. but why is this happening? I still have a problem with other codes. hope I can understand what's happening behind this...

Comment: @falsetru thanks, problem solved. but why is this happening? I still have a problem with other codes. hope I can understand what's happening behind this.